# how to write json data Application Local folder in uwp

Tags: uwp

I am trying to write a large amount of data in JSON format in-app local data in uwp app. I am using await `FileIO.WriteTextAsync(fileName, data);` - the code is working fine in Visual Studio (release and debug modes).

After creating the package and installed on a Windows 10 machine, the file was created successfully but data was not written to it (I have verified by logging that data contains expected JSON string.)

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: Store it in a folder accessible from your UWP app? Does using the IStorageFolder to create and save files produce the same results?

Comment: Hello friends thanks for your time.My code working fine while running using VS.After the installation in another machine the same code not working.ie Suppose i have created a new file named  Data,Json in App local folder.All written data lost or become null when trying to get saved data.

Comment: If you directly use your whole project in another machine and run it, will the same occur? Are the json data to be written the same? And if you write a simple string(e.g. "hello") in another machine, can it be written?

Comment: The simple string is written , JSON also write successfully but all keys set to null.

Comment: It looks like something went wrong when converting the json, can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?

Comment: Hi Faywang i am working on a POC for the same for all three cases which I have tried to fix this.will give here the GitHub link asap.

Comment: OK, I will check it as soon as possible after you uploading it.

Comment: Hi Faywang your Initial observation (that json was not proper converting was correct).So in my POC, i have created a temp JSON of size 4 MB which is taking time to serialize and deserialize as a result app get crashed in release mode(ie when we create a Package and install in the machine).Please find POC here https://github.com/dksingh605/UWP_Apps.git

Comment: When I created a package using your project and installed in the machine, the json read and write worked well, all keys didn't set to null or crash. What's your reproduced steps? What steps caused this error?

Comment: Yes it is working fine for small JSON data but for large JSON file of >4 Mb it is crashing here (my machine has 8 gb RAM I5). Can you please save string of more than 4 mb in UWP Container , On my side when i tried to save a string of size 20 kb it is giving error.

Comment: My machine is 8 GB RAM i7 and I saved a json string more than 4Mb in local folder by using your project, but it still worked well. If you tested in another machine, will the issue occur?